# Excel: Choose Minimum value providing correspondiong cell >20

Tags: microsoft-excel

My spreadsheet contains in *column A* a list of items and in *column B* the quantity of each item:

```
Column A   Column B 
 110         30
 220         30
 380         60
```

I would like to display in a new cells the following logic:

If the *minimal item value* (**110** for the start) is still available in quantity of 20, use minimal value.

If *not* then use then use the **next** minimal value on the list (also provided its quantity is more than 20) and so on.

As a result, it should show in a new array: 110 (10 times), 220 (10 times), 380 (40 times).

I used the formula below to identify the minimal value needed as a next entry

```
=VLOOKUP(MIN(A1:A3),A1:B3,2,0)
```

Lets say 110, 220 and 380 are items (voltage sockets, for example). The column B are the quantities. The stock has to issue the smallest voltage sockets first until its quantity reaches the minimal required quantity that must be always maintained in stock (20). Pulling C1 down, the order of issue of such sockets would be 10x110v (as only 10 can be issued out of 30), then 10x220V (as 220v qty on stock will also become 20) and then issue the 380v ones. what would be the ideal formula for C1 in order to pull that formula down the Column C and the sequence automatically to become 110, 110, 110, ... as it reaches 10 items and becomes 20 in stock, Cell C11 would show its time to start issuing 220v sockets, and cell C21 should show 380, as the previous sockets reach the issuing maximum quantities.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: I'm not following your description.  It might help to see a mockup or screenshot.

Comment: I cannot insert the screenshots right now, but idea is  the new cell to choose the smallest amount in column A, find corresponding number in column B and insert one of its quantity numbers,provided the quantity value is still bigger than 20. when pull the cell down, it should do the same, dispersing "1"  to each cell.  these numbers automatically must be subtracted from  the total, until it reaches 20. after, the next minimal value with the quantity of 20will  be entered and so on.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below solution, the stock will be delivered in sequence of column A. So, if you want to deliver the lowest voltage first, please sort column A first.

1. Enter into C1 `0`.
2. Enter into C2 `=IF(A1,MAX(B1-20,0)+C1,"")`, and copy downwards.
3. Enter into D1 `=IF(ROW(D1)<=MAX(C:C),INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(D1)-1,C:C,1)),"")`, and copy downwards. Column D will be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

How many items do you have? As long as there is only a small number of items then the following might work:

In cell C1 type:

```
=IF(B1>20,A1,IF(B2>20,A2,IF(B3>20,A3,"No Stock")))
```

If there is less than 21 stock available of a particular item then the next item is checked for its stock number. If none have at least 20 available then it will provide the relevant text, or "" if you just want blank.

The more stock items, the longer the string, though.